# Вывести список клиентов, средняя стоимость заказа которых > средней стоимости заказов по кафе

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, запрос

У меня есть база данных кафе и необходимо "Вывести список клиентов, средняя стоимость заказа которых > средней стоимости заказов по кафе"

Как правильно составить запрос, чтобы суммировать именно по каждому клиенту?

```
insert into customer values(1001, 'Mary', 89039388469);
insert into customer values(1002, 'Alex', 89139372469);

insert into waiter values(1, 'Mark', 1001);
insert into waiter values(2, 'Alena', 1002);

insert into orders values(64, 1001, 1, 154);
insert into orders values(65, 1002, 2, 155);
insert into orders values(66, 1001, 1, 156);

insert into bill values(1, 1001, '05 Dec 2020', 2000, 64);
insert into bill values(3, 1001, '05 Dec 2020', 2000, 66);
insert into bill values(2, 1002, '05 Dec 2020', 5000, 65);

insert into chef values(100, 'Mikhail', 30000);

insert into dish values(123, 1290, array ['Apple','Mint'], 100, 'Juice');
insert into dish values(124, 1290, array ['Fish','Lemon'], 100, 'Dorado');
insert into dish values(125, 1290, array ['Chicken','Oil'], 100, 'Chicken grill');

insert into ingredient values(12, array ['Apple','Mint'], 120, 123, 350, 50);
insert into ingredient values(13, array ['Fish','Lemon'], 220, 124, 550, 350);
insert into ingredient values(14, array ['Chicken','Oil'], 350, 125, 250, 250);

insert into order_item values(64, 123, 250, 1);
insert into order_item values(65, 124, 650, 1);                         
insert into order_item values(66, 125, 500, 1); 

                       
insert into restaurant values('DrovaMuka', 'Lenina, 12', 'Italian', 89234532871);




create table customer ( 
  ID int primary key,
  Name varchar(40),
  phone numeric(11,0) not null
);
  

create table waiter (
  ID int primary key, 
  Name varchar(40),
  customer_id int, 
  foreign key (customer_id) references customer(ID)
);

create table orders (
  ID int primary key,
  customer_id int not null, 
  foreign key (customer_id) references customer(ID),
  waiter_id int not null, 
  foreign key (waiter_id) references waiter(ID),
  order_number int not null
);

create table bill (
  ID int primary key,
  customer_id int not null, 
  foreign key (customer_id) references customer(ID),
  "date" date,
  total_cost int not null,
  order_id int not null,
  foreign key (order_id) references orders(ID)
);

create table chef (
  ID int primary key,
  Name varchar(40),
  salary int not null
);

create table dish (
  ID int primary key,
  price int not null,
  ingredients text array,
  chef_id int not null,
  foreign key (chef_id) references chef(ID),
  Name varchar(40)
  
);

create table ingredient (
  ID int primary key,
  Name text array,
  weight int not null,
  dish_id int not null,
  foreign key (dish_id) references dish(ID),
  calories int not null,
  price int not null
);

create table restaurant (
  Name varchar(40) primary key,
  adress varchar(20),
  kitchen_type varchar(10),
  phone numeric(11,0) not null
);


create table order_item (
  order_id int not null,
  foreign key (order_id) references orders(ID),
  dish_id int not null,
  foreign key (dish_id) references dish(ID),
  price int not null, 
  qty int not null
);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=18e6734b1683b228131395b3934dc42e

Comment: Средняя стоимость заказа считается соответствующей оконной функцией в требуемом разрезе. Делают это в CTE. А во внешнем  запросе выполняют отбор по полученным данным.

Comment: спасибо за замечание, исправил на текст! но решение все равно непонятно

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример получения нужного ответа, когда есть посчитанные стоимости отдельных заказов:

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *,
                     AVG(summa) OVER () avg_cafe, -- средний заказ по всему кафе
                     AVG(summa) OVER (PARTITION BY client) avg_client -- и по клиенту
              FROM test )
SELECT DISTINCT client
FROM cte
WHERE avg_client > avg_cafe;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6a7707c36d0dce5eaba30844dfa1a2d0

Ну а посчитать суммы заказов (тривиальные JOIN и агрегация) - это уж Вы как-нибудь самостоятельно...